# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

In reactjs, I am using the `ant-design` library for a form. In the console i face this problem:

> ```
> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>
> ```

Can someone show me what mistake I made in my code?

[image]

**code**

```
import React, { component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './FirstStep.css';
import { Form, Input } from 'antd';
class RegisterStepOne extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <FormCard>
          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
            <FormItem>
              {getFieldDecorator('firstName', {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your First name!',
                    whitespace: true,
                  },
                ],
              })(<Input placeholder="First name" />)}
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem>
              {getFieldDecorator('lastName', {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your Last name!',
                    whitespace: true,
                  },
                ],
              })(<Input placeholder="Last name" />)}
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem>
              {getFieldDecorator('email', {
                rules: [
                  {
                    type: 'email',
                    message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
                  },
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
                  },
                ],
              })(<Input placeholder="Email" />)}
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem>
              {getFieldDecorator('lastPosition', {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your Last Position!',
                    whitespace: true,
                  },
                ],
              })(<Input placeholder="Present or last position" />)}
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem>
              {getFieldDecorator('lastCompany', {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your Last Company!',
                    whitespace: true,
                  },
                ],
              })(<Input placeholder="Present or last Company" />)}
            </FormItem>
          </Form>
        </FormCard>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default RegisterStepOne;
```

Comment: Is `RegisterStepOne` used in some `Form`? Could you show its parent? What is `FormCard`? I can't see it in imports

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question with different formatting and edited the html element `<form>` to `&lt;form>` as this is flagged by the system for anti spam measures. You should also stick to just the problem, and try not to repeat yourself.

Comment: @DarkMukke I've also gone ahead and reintroduced the `<form>` tags, but with the correct formatting (Indenting to format it as code). I've also removed some noise, as "Thanks!", "Much Appreciated", which usually detracts from the question at hand.

Comment: @FrankerZ yes much better, I did introduce a > out of nowhere that I removed.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the console screenshot suggests that `<RegisterStepOne />` is a child of a `<form>` somewhere higher up the component tree.

You are seeing the error because your DOM renders to something like this

```
<form>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input />
    </form>
  </div>
</form>
```

Which is not valid HTML

Comment: @Brad RegisterStepOne contains a form and is also a child of a form. The parent form is coming from Form (Created by Wizard). Paste the code where you are rendering RegisterStepOne and we can help further

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have DOM nesting error.
Cause of dom tree, `<form>` in `<form>` as follows:

```html
<form>
    <form></form>
</form>
```

If you want serve this,
you'll change your form dom tree nesting.